# multilevel array get exact value from json file using php

Tags: php, json

i have htis json file:

```
{
    "waluta": "EUR",
    "vat": 1,
    "01_00101": {
        "cena": 130.8,
        "kod": "00101",
        "nazwa": "Span TRICK 1200/1982-ABS",
        "powiazanyZ": "00139"
    },
    "01_00102": {
        "cena": 125.86,
        "kod": "00102",
        "nazwa": "Span TRICK 1200/1864-ABS",
        "powiazanyZ": "00140"
    },
    "02_00122": {
        "cena": 0,
        "kod": "00122",
        "nazwa": "SET to Wicket TRICK 1200 elektrolock RIGHT",
        "powiazanyZ": "00000"
    },
    "02_00123": {
        "cena": 0,
        "kod": "00123",
        "nazwa": "SET to Wicket TRICK 1200 elektrolock LEFT",
        "powiazanyZ": "00000"
    },
    "02_00152": {
        "cena": 0,
        "kod": "00115",
        "nazwa": "Gate ABS 1200/3070 prepared to servomotor ARM 400",
        "powiazanyZ": "00138"
    },
    "02_00138": {
        "cena": 0,
        "kod": "00115",
        "nazwa": "Gate ABS 1200/3070 handle, bolt",
        "powiazanyZ": "00152"
    }
}
```

and in my php code i read this like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("cennik-en.json");
$cennik_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

and i would like to access values by "kod" value. is this possible?
because by key value i think i can do like that:

```
$json_a['01_00101'][nazwa];
```

Comment: Post `var_dump($cennik_a);` so we can see how json_decode() is handling this. More likely than array keys, you're getting back stdClass objects in an array like `$cennik_a['02_00138']->cena`

Comment: he's using json_decode() passing true as second param makes it decode as array so it won't be a stdClass

Comment: Yes, but quote strings to avoid errors and / or constants problems: `$json_a['01_00101']['nazwa'];` & `$json_a['01_00101']['kod'];`

Comment: does something like function **returnMainKey(kod){}** that do loop over every key to check which one has value i need **('kod')** and would return main key (for example '01_00101'), then i would access it by `$json_a['01_00101']["nazwa"];` or `$json_a['01_00101']["cena"];` would work? if yes, anyone can help?

Comment: Yes, loop over the array and check which has the "kod" value you require

Comment: any example that i can use for my need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function returnMainKey( $json, $kod) {
    foreach( $json as $key => $value)
        if( is_array( $value))
            if( isset( $value["kod"]) && $value["kod"] == $kod)
                return $key;
    return null;
}

$string = file_get_contents("cennik-en.json");
$cennik_a=json_decode($string,true);
$key = returnMainKey( $cennik_a, "00101");
echo $cennik_a[$key]["nazwa"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the "kod" value like so:

```
$kod = $json_a['01_00101']["kod"];
```

In your example above, you're trying to access with `[nazwa]` when it should be `["nazwa"]` as the keys are strings.

Comment: i think, i was not clear. i would need an access to 'nazwa', 'cena' values using 'kod' value as a key

Comment: In that case, you'll want to loop through the array checking ['kod'] against the value you're searching for, then return the ['nazwa'] for that array index

Comment: i am trying to use: `function getMainKey($kod) {
    foreach (cennik_a as $key => $value) {
  if ($key != "waluta" && $key != "vat") {
   if($value["kod"] == $kod){
    return $key;
   }
  }
 }
}` and getting a result for example using: `echo getMainKey("00115");` but without success. what is wrong? it gives me an error **b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/public_html/test/print.php**

Comment: The error message says that the argument in your foreach is invalid. What exactly is cennik_a?  Do you mean `$cennik_a` ?